# Incorrect timezone javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime-format

For below function, I'm not able to get the right time for parsedFromServer object. It works, if I take current time but it doesnt work for date selected from date selector. Can anyone help me what's wrong in it?

```
 //value from date selector
const dateObject = Object.values(value)); // returns Sat 01 Oct 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Standard Time)

  var localDate = new Date();
 console.log("localDate", localDate); // localDate Tue Aug 16 2022 13:14:48 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
  var offset = -(localDate.getTimezoneOffset() / 60);
  const dateFromServer = new Date(
      localDate.getTime() + offset * 3600 * 1000,
  ).toUTCString();

  var serverDate = new Date(dateObject);
  console.log("serverDate", serverDate); //serverDate Wed Nov 16 2022 08:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
  offset = -(serverDate.getTimezoneOffset() / 60);
  const parsedFromServer = new Date(
      serverDate.getTime() + offset * 3600 * 1000,
  ).toUTCString();
  

  console.log("dateFromServer", dateFromServer); //returns correct-> Tue, 16 Aug 2022 12:31:20 GMT
  console.log("parsedFromServer", parsedFromServer); //incorrect ->  Sat, 01 Oct 2022 00:00:00 GMT.
```

Also, i have noticed difference in daylight time and standard time

Comment: can you provide the relevant code that shows how you retrieve value? I used an input date as date selector and retrieve value by element id and all works fine

Comment: It returns this  new Date(date) and value of date is like this 2022-08-17T07:00:00Z

Comment: please update the question with the relevant code, it would be more clear for all readers

Comment: What would the correct time be for the parsedFromServer date?

Comment: @JeremyKahan, ok so parsedFromServer should have time included like dateFromServer object

Comment: but the dateObject from which it is initialized does not have it. I must be missing something.

Comment: @JeremyKahan value comes from here -> const dateObject = Object.values(value));  and the value = {decisionDate: Tue Nov 15 2022 08:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)}, so Object.values returns actual datetime value

Comment: Ok. I read the comment on the dateObject line that said returns Sat 01 Oct 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0700 and got confused.

Comment: 13:14 minus 7 hours is not 12:31. Why do you say it's a correct result? I would say that both your code blocks are equally incorrect because it is mixing UTC (TZ-free) functions with some strange TZ offset calculation.